# Bash Set cursor in prompt using expansion

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I'm trying to set the cursor in place to make an autocompletion later in prompt, but I'm not achieving the desired result. The action goes like this:

First, I define a variable to expand like a command I use very often

```
my_command="script_name parameter1 /some/path/ parameterN"
```

As I want to place the cursor at the end of `/some/path/` then I define another variable as:

```
set_cursor='$my_command; $(echo -en "\033[10D")'
```

Then I type `$set_cursor` on the prompt and the first expansion goes well, but the second just prints

```
script_name parameter1 /some/path/ parameterN; ^[[10D
```

Instead of setting the cursor in place.

What is the point i'm missing? I suppose this can be achieved, but I'm misunderstanding the use or having some misconception.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using shell expansion of readline (ESC, CTRL-E)?

Comment: Yes, precisely CTRL+META+E. But I tried your sequence and the bind seems the same. In fact bind -p show yours '"\e\C-e": shell-expand-line'

Comment: I asked this just to confirm that you are trying to achieve your goal through readline shell expansion functionality. I think that's impossible. Why don't you use the auto-completion functionality?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point. I use autocompletion, but I'd like to save me the manual cursor positioning after the expansion (which places the cursor at the end of line). Are you meaning something else? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Run this command in your shell: `bind '"\C-xr": "script_name parameter1 /some/path/ parameterN\e[D\e[D\e[D\e[D\e[D\e[D\e[D\e[D\e[D\e[D"'`. Then type `CTRL-x, r`. Does it do what you need?

Comment: Nice trick :) This seems a suitable solution. But according to http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html it can be parametrized with the number of positions. In practice it seems it can't. Also why this doesn't work when defined in a variable instead of bounded to a key? This seems very confusing to me.

Comment: Terminal control sequences don't work when a variable is expanded on the command line. To this end, during expansion bash represents the byte "\033" as `^[`, though it keeps being treated as a single character (which can be checked with cursor motion). Similarly that same symbol can be inserted on the command line with `CTRL-V`, `ESC`.

Comment: Note that the trick with `bind` doesn't rely on ANSI escape sequences. It uses a readline macro, which emulates keypresses (`\e[D` stands for the left arrow key).